# Is there a way to step through the preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm trying to debug some `boost::fusion` stuff, and this would be exceedingly helpful, and I see no reason it's impossible - there's a stack of defined symbols and something analogous to a cursor/current position - has anyone built this?

Comment: I feel bad about it too.

Comment: Uhh, what you *can* do is printf debugging by sprinkling `#warning` everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your code through the Boost.Wave preprocessor that offers tracing facility: http://www.boost.org/libs/wave/doc/tracing_facility.html

Just wrap the code you want to trace in

```
#pragma wave trace(enable)
...
#pragma wave trace(disable)
```

and then run it with `--traceto <trace-filename>` command line argument, like

```
wave --traceto test.trace test.cpp
```

The `test.trace` file will have all the details of the macro expansion process of the traced part of your code.